# Get back command line prompt after starting a process that will take time to quit

Tags: command-line-interface

I have a script that I use to sever my current directory through a port. Its called server.

I can do the following to run it in the background: `server &`. But how can I suspend the server even after starting and get the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this question/answer as I found this very useful:

We can suspend any process using `Ctrl-z` and get back the prompt. And to go back to the process use `fg`, meaning *foreground*.